# Network responses got buffer overwritten in stress?

Tags: java, networking, netty

i've been debugging this issue hardly for two days. And i cannot find an answer after quite a lot searches in/outside stackoverflow.

I'm writing a client for customized key/value server. The protocol is simple.
If the client send

```
"GET 1 12\r\nkey1\r\nkey2\r\n"
```

the server may replay

```
"0 1 16\r\nvalue1\r\nvalue2\r\n"
```

In the response, first line says the length of body is 16 bytes, and for the next 16 bytes, it contains to values for the two keys. They're seperated by "\r\n".

**The problem is that, in stress testing, sometime I see from my client ,the response message looks malformed. It looks like the buffer is overwritten.**

e.g. send

```
"GET 1 12\r\nkey1\r\nkey2\r\n"
```

for 10k times,
In response buffer i might see

```
"0 1 16\r\nvalue1\r\nval0 1 16"
```

It looks like value2 here is partially overwritten by the next response.

The server has been working there for long time, and I assume it works well. I also use tcpdump and prove it's correct. So the bug should be in client.

I followed the Netty Telnet example [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/telnet), and did small modification.

After DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder, a handler parses the lines one by one and assembles the response.

I thought it could be related with multi-thread. But even I set thread number to 1, the problem repros.

So do I use Netty in an incorrect way?

====================

**Update:**
After more investigation, I found it's not related with Netty. Even with a simple java NIO program, it could repro. It seems it's related with buffer overflow.

From tcpdump, I can see the packages from remote server is correct.

So I capture every ByteBuffer, and print it out when bug happens. (I deliberately set the buffer size to a small number - 1k.) with this code:

```
protected void onRead(ByteBuffer buf) throws Exception {
        buf.mark();
        int l = buf.limit();
        int p = buf.position();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[l - p];
        buf.get(bytes, p, l - p);
        String v = new String( bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8") );
        buffers.addFirst(v);
        if (buffers.size() > 30) {
            buffers.removeLast();
        }
        buf.reset();
        //...
        // process one line of buf

};
```

The following are the last three buffer capture, as I process it line by line. It seems the head "0 0 1040" is wrong placed a truncated line "20"

```
*************************************
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
0 0 1040^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
200 0 1040^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M

*************************************
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
0 0 1040^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20
*************************************
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
0 0 1040^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/booking.com.png^M
20131101/boo
*************************************
```

I didn't figure the root cause yet. I'll reply it once I got the answer.

=====================

Here's my original code snippets,
initializer

```
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast(DECODER);
        pipeline.addLast(ENCODER);

        pipeline.addLast(new NettyClientHandler());
    }
```

and handler:

```
//@Sharable
public class NettyClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {
    boolean head = true;
    int len = -1;
    ArrayList<String> vals = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String request) throws InterruptedException {
        if (head) {
            vals.clear();
            String[] splits = request.split(" ");
            len = -1;
            try {
                len = Integer.parseInt(splits[2]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (len == -1) {
                return;
            }
            head = false;
        } else {
            vals.add(request);
            len -= (request.length() + 2);
            if (len == 0) {
//                System.err.print("[");
//                for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++) {
//                    System.err.print(vals.get(i) + ",");
//                }
//                System.err.println("]");
                head = true;
            }
        }
        //System.err.println(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After investigation, the result is a little disappointing. The server has a bug.

In retrospect, there's something I learned here.

- TCP cannot be wrong. I was considering buffer overflow or something,
  but TCP has congestion control, so this could not happen;
- I could use a much simple program to test server, e.g. a simple
  two-thread old-IO program.
- ncat is the easist way to verify this, that is, to prepare large
  packages and use ncat to get the response~

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming there is such a thing as a message in TCP. There isn't. It's a byte stream. It can deliver you zero, one, or more bytes according entirely to its whim. If you're expecting a specific message length, it is up to you to either loop until you get it, if it is less, or split what you've already received, if it is more.